# Swift: RSS feed, saving a user's favorites locally

Tags: ios, swift, rss

I'm currently creating an app that has the following architecture:

- ViewController - this displays a list of RSS items (articles) at summary level
- DetailedViewController - this displayed the RSS item (article) selected in more detail
- FeedModel - this parses the RSS feed and creates the article objects
- Article - this is the specifics of the article object

The articles are news items for sporting players, and what I'm currently trying to do is allow the user to click a button on the DetailedViewController to "save" that sporting player, so that I can implement a "MyPlayersViewController" which will show articles only pertaining to the players they have saved. My issue is that when I save the player's unique ID to a "MyPlayersArray" in the "DetailedViewController" I lose the ability to keep that information stored, so when the user goes back to the ViewController and then into another article about the same player the app has forgotten which players have been saved.

Any tips on how I should be trying to implement this or what I should read would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want persist data across many user sessions (user could close app and come back later) use `NSUserDefaults` it will save your `playerID`s to disk

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:<youArrayOfIDs> forKey:"myPlayerIDsArray"]; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardIserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Also check out core data if you want to save a lot of data to disk

If you are looking to prevent your objects from being lost when dismissing `viewController`s declare your variables in `appDelegate`

```
myDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
MyPlayersArray=myDelegate.myPlayerIDsArray
//where myPlayerIDsArray is an object declared in your appDelegate which won't loose its data until app is active
```

Also you can prefix `static` before object declaration so it will always be saved during app current lifecycle